# conda : SSLError(SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(104, 'ECONNRESET')",),),) conda

Tags: python, conda

I want to use miniconda3 to install a package but it pops that error:

```
 Solving environment: failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json.bz2>

Elapsed: -
   An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL. HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(104, 'ECONNRESET')",),),)
```

BTW, the miniconda2 runs wells only miniconda3 has the problem.

PS. I also tried to use `wget  --no-check-certificate` to download the file and got the error too:

```
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/repodata.json.bz2
--2019-03-14 02:03:44--  https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/repodata.json.bz2
Resolving repo.anaconda.com (repo.anaconda.com)... 104.16.130.3, 
104.16.131.3, 2606:4700::6810:8303, ...
Connecting to repo.anaconda.com (repo.anaconda.com)|104.16.130.3|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

The system is CentOS and I have already use `sudo yum update` to update the sys file and library.

Comment: Have you tried searching [the Anaconda issues repository](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues)? Seems like others have had similar issues, e.g., [this thread](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9504#issuecomment-397278896) implies that using `ssl_verify: false` is problematic. It may help to also post output from `conda info` and `cat ~/.condarc`.